# Why doesn't the object get passed into the 'class property'?

Tags: php, oop

This feels like its obvious...
I've created these two classes in php but I'm struggling to understand why the object doesn't seem to be passed back.

```
    class DataAccess {

    function dbconnect($query){
        @ $db = new mysqli(MYHOST,MYDBUSER,DBUSERPASSWORD,MYDATABASE);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo '<h1>there is an error with the database connection</h1>';
            exit;
        }    
        $result = $db->query($query);
        $db->close();
        return $result;
    }
```

and...

```
    class Run {

    public $getdata;
    public $jobdetails;

    function __construct(){
        $query = 'Select ID from jobs;';
        $getdata = new DataAccess();            

        $jobdetails = $getdata->dbconnect($query);
    }

    function getJobList(){
    print_r ($this->jobdetails);

    }
}
```

and I call using this:

```
$mything = new Run();
```

now if I `print_r($result);` from inside the dbconnect function it returns metadata, but if I do it once it's passed back to the Run class, it doesn't return anything. 
What am I missing?

Comment: You should read some documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php , especially: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: I did read the documentation and it doesn't specifically mention anything about the scope of the properties, which is what I missed. It's late, I'm tired ;-)

Comment: Don't wanna be picky, but the second link says *Within class methods the properties, constants, and methods may be accessed by using the form `$this->property` (where `property` is the name of the property)* ;) Anyway, you got your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$jobdetails = $getdata->dbconnect($query);
```

To this:

```
$this->jobdetails = $getdata->dbconnect($query);
```

Answer (score 3):

$jobdetails is local to __construct, if you want to have it local to the instance, use $this->jobdetails

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't make a DB connection for each query you run. Connect in the constructor and then the connection will be closed automatically when the script ends

```
class DataAccess {

    protected $_connection = null;

    function __construct() {
        $this->_connection = new mysqli(MYHOST,MYDBUSER,DBUSERPASSWORD,MYDATABASE);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo '<h1>there is an error with the database connection</h1>';
            exit;
        }
    }

    function query($query){   
        return $this->_connection->query($query);
    }

}
```

Secondly, you're not setting the instance variable properly.

Change:

```
$jobdetails = $getdata->dbconnect($query);
```

To:

```
$this->jobdetails = $getdata->dbconnect($query);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on creating the connection in the construct. I'm just changing this application from a procedural methodology to OOP so I may not have noticed that building the connection into the construct was a bit more efficient. I'd like to think that I would... ;-)